# Где лучше хранить данные и с помощью чего?

Tags: python, база-данных, python-3.x

Ситуация такая. Есть примерно одна сотня записей такого вида:

```
{'name': 'Yuri',
 'start': 55,
 'enemies': ('Nick', 'Lora', 'Frank', 'Bernard', 'Phoebee', 'Jack',
             'Cristina', 'Stephen', 'Joe', 'Gary', 'Robert')}
```

Это одна запись. Ранее для их хранения использовался модуль `shelve`. Сейчас же нужно что-то кроссплатформенное, и я не знаю, что мне выбрать. Данные в будущем не будут изменяться программой или как-то дополняться, они останутся точно такими же.

Всё, что будет происходить "внутри", это получение информации из этих словарей: например, по имени `Yuri` нужно будет найти `start` и его `enemies` и, если среди них есть `Lora`, то найти и её `enemies`, ну и в этом роде. Был вариант использовать `csv`, но я не уверен, хороший ли это выбор в данном случае. Какие есть предложения? Обоснуйте свой ответ, пожалуйста.

Comment: Для одной сотни записей подойдёт вообще что угодно

Comment: @andreymal Даже если сделать, скажем, словарь словарей или список словарей? Важна скорость, но это не особо критично.

Comment: Для одной сотни записей быстрым будет вообще что угодно. Вот если бы записей было сотня миллионов, тогда бы это стало проблемой :) Ну и в любом случае можно самостоятельно измерить производительность всех доступных способов и выбрать самый быстрый

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для такого объема данных и с учетом того, что они не изменяются и должны быть доступны кросплатформенно, вам стоит посмотреть в сторону JSON.

В нем легко хранить объекты типа словарей и инструменты для работы с JSON есть в стандартной библиотеки почти каждого ЯП.

Comment: Если я с помощью `json` сохраню словарь словарей в файл `data.json`, то при доставании данных из записи лучше открывать один из словарей, тем самым открывая файл каждый раз (`json.load(file)['ключ']`), или же сперва загрузить весь словарь словарей в переменную, а потом доставать данные из переменной (`data = json.load(file); data['ключ']`)? Плохо ли скажется открывание файла раз десять за секунду?

Comment: @Newbie второй вариант, нет смысла дергать файл постоянно - это относительно медленная операция